# Does Resveratrol increase human life expectancy?

Tags: nutrition, nutritional-supplements, life-expectancy

> Resveratrol is a buzz word in health science research.  It is hailed
> as the discovery of “the fountain of  youth” .   In the past 10 years
> over 500 medical research studies were performed. These studies
> consistently demonstrate that life expectancy can be increased an
> adjusted  25 to 35 years, as evidenced by good animal studies.
> [Naturalhealthsecrets](http://naturalhealthsecrets.ws/1180/resveratrol-the-amazing-longevity-breakthrough/)

What's the state of the evidence that Resveratrol does, in fact, increase human life expectancy? (Even if the effect is lower than those 25 to 35 years).

Comment: I searched a bit about it and found many unreliable pages (like the one you linked) which all claim that Resveratrol is the fountain of youth. They also state that there are hundreds of studies but none of these sites linked to one. What I also found was site that sell you that (rather pricy) stuff... Wikipedia states that the research of Resveratrol on humans is still in its infancy. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resveratrol#cite_note-The_Connecticut_Post_2009-9) I would say it's just a hype and a good way to make a lot of money.

Comment: 33 reviews in the literature: http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?start=20&q=allintitle:+Resveratrol+review

Answer (score 1):

**Resveratrol (3,5,4'-trihydroxy-trans-stilbene) is a non-flavonoid polyphenol present in grapes and red wine. Per Joao Tomé-Carneiro et.al in [2013](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3782695/), Resveratrol (RES) exerts cardioprotective benefits through the improvement of inflammatory markers, atherogenic profile, glucose metabolism and endothelial function according to the clinical trials conducted so far**. These effects have been observed using both high and low doses of Resveratrol and both in healthy volunteers and medicated patients. **However, the specific mechanisms by which this may occur are not yet clear. More trials are needed to confirm other possible effects and mechanisms.** The promising neurodegenerative and cancer chemopreventive effects of Resveratrol in animal models have not been yet confirmed in humans.

**A classical drawback for this molecule has been the poor bioavailability of RES despite the effects observed.** A recurrent criticism used by some physicians/pharmacologists is that 'RES cannot exert benefits because it is rapidly metabolized and its presence in the bloodstream is negligible to justify any effect'. **However, the effects exist. More research should focus on identifying the actual metabolites, signals or mediators responsible for these effects.**

> In addition, and to overcome the poor bioavailabilty of RES, intense research has been performed to enhance its bioavailability. After RES intake, the actual metabolite responsible (if any) for the effects exerted is still unknown. The specific activity associated to known metabolites has been scarcely investigated.
>
> The objective of using high doses of RES with a pharmacological use is still unclear. Safety concerns, easy and cheap commercial availability of the molecule, and lack of added value for pharmaceutical companies make the future of RES, as a possible pharmaceutical multitarget drug, rather obscure.